# How can I get chosen shipping method in an email PDF using variables?

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, pdf

I am trying to query the shipping method chosen in order to display an image of shipping method logo i.e Royal Mail, DPD etc

The problem is that I am not very familiar with the way the shipping variable is being parsed to the template using `{{var shipping}}` so I'm not sure how I could do an `IF`

For example:

```
    <?php if('{{var shipping}}' === 'ROYAL MAIL') :?>
    <td style=" float: left; " valign="top">
        <p><?php echo $this->__("ROYAL MAIL:") ?></p>
    </td>
    <?php else :?>
    <td style=" float: left;" valign="top">
        <p><?php echo $this->__("DPD") ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif ?>
```

I know that this isn't the correct way so I wanted to ask how I could query using using these template variables?

Comment: You can use the tag `{{depend}}` if your template to test against a variable like so : 
`{{depend myvar}}<td>something something</td>{{/depend}}`

Comment: are you working on html email template

Comment: @JulienLachal Thankyou for your input, I was wonder how I could use this to check which shipping method was used  as there is only one variable for shipping I'm sure how I'd make the if

Comment: you can get shipping method details from  shipping_method and shipping_information field order object

Answer (score 1):

Try with `$order->getData('shipping_method')` to get the shipping method code and `$order->getShippingDescription()` to get the shipinng method label.